# how to reshape spark df without aggregating

Tags: apache-spark, pivot, databricks

I went through all topics on stac but still have problem.
I have a lot of data, so I can't use Python, I started with spark but I struggled with pivot.

I have written a code in Python:

```
gl = f"""select 
        a.name
        ,extract (month from a.transactiondate) as monthid
        ,extract(year from a.transactiondate) as yearid
        ,replace(logistic,' ',',') as logistic
        ,sum(value) as SpendingsLogisticGroup
        ,count(distinct a.ticketid) as TicketsLogisticGroup
        ,sum(qte) as QuantityLogisticGroup
        ,coalesce(sum(discount),0) as DiscountLogisticGroup
        ,coalesce(sum (case when discoun / (discount + nvalue) >= 0.1 then value end),0) as SpendingsPromoLogisticGroup
        ,coalesce(sum (case when value / (value + nvalue) >= 0.1 then quantity end),0) as QuantityPromoLogisticGroup
        from table1 a
        join table2 c on a.Product = c.Article
        where
        
        length(a.customerid)>10
        and a.transaction between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-30'
        group by 1,2,3,4"""

gl = sql(gl) 
gl = ks.DataFrame(gl) ## from koalas DF
gl = gl.pivot_table(index=['name', 'yearid', 'monthid'], columns='logistic',
                                values=['SpendingsLogisticGroup', 
                                        'TicketsLogisticGroup', 
                                        'QuantityLogisticGroup',
                                       'DiscountLogisticGroup',
                                       'SpendingsPromoLogisticGroup',
                                       'QuantityPromoLogisticGroup'], fill_value=0)
gl.columns = ["_".join(map(str, i)) for i in gl.columns.to_flat_index()]
gl.columns = gl.columns.str.replace(",", "_")
gl.columns = gl.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
gl.columns = gl.columns.str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', errors = 'ignore').str.decode('utf-8')
```

This code works pretty fine in Python but I have to rewrite it to spark.
I tried with something like this:

```
pivot = gl.groupBy("customerid", "monthid","yearid").pivot("logisticgroupname",['SpendingsLogisticGroup','TicketsLogisticGroup']).agg(first(col("logisticgroupname")))
```

but it doesn't work.

What I need is to have this result:

[image: result]

from df like below:

[image: first picture]

but using only Spark (not PandasSpark or even KoalasSpark)

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: can you explain what you have and what you want as a results ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main question here is how to create a pivot using PySpark!  The code below was created and tested on Azure Databricks.

1 - Lets find a sample data set.  There are a ton of free ones on each installation.  Lets use the bike share data.

[image]

2 - Find the file location and file type.  We are going to use the hourly dataset that is in a csv format.

[image]

3 - Read the data into a Spark dataframe.  At the same time, exposed the dataframe as a temporary table.  Who wants to learn all those dataframe methods when SQL is so simple?

```
# path to data
path = 'dbfs:/databricks-datasets/bikeSharing/data-001/hour.csv'

# create data frame
df1 = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("sep", ",") \
  .option("multiLine", "false") \
  .load(path)

# make temp hive view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_bike_shares")

# Show data
display(df1)
```

[image]

4 - Lets reduce the number of fields to 5: year, quarter, temperature, humidity, and windspeed.

[image]

5 - Regardless if we use SQL or dataframe methods, a pivot command always uses an aggregation function.  That is how it is defined.

```
%sql
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT year(dteday) yr, quarter(dteday) qtr, temp as tmp, hum, windspeed
  FROM tmp_bike_shares
  WHERE dteday BETWEEN DATE '2011-01-01' AND DATE '2013-01-01'
)
PIVOT 
(
  avg(tmp), min(hum), max(windspeed)
  FOR qtr in (
    1 Q1, 2 Q2, 3 Q3, 4 Q4
  )
)
ORDER BY yr
```

[image]

The column headings are a combination of the pivot column values cross the aggregate columns for each value.  Personally, I would just rename the columns before saving.

At this point it is very easy to covert the Spark SQL code into python code that produces a dataframe, repartitions the data and saves the data to a file format of your choosing.

In short, the answer is pivots are supported in spark.  Please look at the data and code in your use case.